# Firefox doesn't honor "Remember Me" choice on websites (persistent cookies)

Tags: firefox, cookies

I've noticed for a while that I have to manually log back in to websites frequently even when I check "remember me" to enable permanent or long-lasting cookies. I always thought it was an extension causing the problem, but recently I reinstalled my OS (Arch Linux) and it happens on the latest Firefox (30.0) even with no extensions installed. For one website that exhibits this problem, Hall.com, I even reached out to them about it but they couldn't find any problem on their end. After logging in, there is a rembember_user_token cookie that is set to expire in 3 years. Is this a bug, or could there be anything else preventing the cookie from being stored?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been this issue:

**Firefox does not remember login information<sup>1</sup>**

It may be due to a corrupted `cookies.sqlite` file in Firefox's profile folder. In order to fix this, just rename or remove `cookie.sqlite` while Firefox is not running.

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx.default/
rm -f cookies.sqlite
```

**Note:** `xxxxxxxx` represents a random string of 8 characters.

Restart Firefox and see if it solved the problem.

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>**Source:** https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/firefox#Firefox_does_not_remember_login_information</sub>

Comment: I answered too soon. The issue persists. Could it be the server is invalidating my cookie when my IP address changes (due to proxy)?

Comment: It indeed worked the first time I removed the `cookies.sqlite`. But now (after a day) it's broken again. Removing `cookies.sqlite` does no longer fix the issue (even temporarily).